# Error on flutter : type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary

I have this Json. I want to map my json data. But i get some error.

```
{
"Id": 0,
"Product_Id": 0,
"Quantity": 0,
"User_Id": "a49a10d2-fc3f-477a-b087-5b0d07545964",
"Active": false,
"CartProducts": null,
"Products": [
    {
        "Id": 116,
        "Shop_Id": 1,
        "Offer": 0.0,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Price": 100.0,
        "Category_Id": 0,
        "Description": null,
        "Name": "Lacoste Product",
        "Active": false,
        "Size": "small",
        "Color": "black",
        "Is_External_Product": true,
        "External_Link": "https://www.lacoste.com.tr/urun/kadin-kirmizi-polo-pf0504-007-4/",
        "Currency": null,
        "ProductImages": null
    }
]
}
```

I am decoding Json here

```
if(jsonObject['Products']!=null){
  productItems = ProductItem.getListFromJson(jsonObject['Products']);
}

static List<ProductItem> getListFromJson(List<dynamic> jsonArray) {
log("getListFromJson");
List<ProductItem> list = [];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length; i++) {
  list.add(ProductItem.fromJson(jsonArray[i]));
}
return list;
 }
```

But i get this error. "[log] type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String'"

Comment: show your model

Comment: Do you get a line where the error occurs? Because `jsonArray[i]` is of type `dynamic` and you are passing it into your `fromJson` function.
What are you supposed to pass into the `fromJson`? A `List` or does it expect a `String`?

Comment: i am passing a list (Products). I have a list in a json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a JSON parsing issue, and it might not directly related to "Products" as being a list or string.

So instead, for better diagnosing this error, or other error on the future, you could need to enable the dart debugger, while checking the "uncaught exception" option, which will guide you to the broken type casting issue.

[image: Enable dart debugger for uncaught exceptions]

Comment: How can i open this setting window?

Comment: @CihanKalmaz If you are using the Visual Studio Code, you can use the ( ⌘ + ⇧ + D) or open the run & Debug from the left side menu.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a value of type String to the product items array. There might be a possibility one of your responses is returning a String and you are expecting an array. Please inspect the response.